# property file not loading spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

My property file is location in src/main/resources in eclipse checked its in the classpath - however the following class is unable to initialize the env variable. Any help?

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate;


@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:solr.properties" })
public class SolrConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;
private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SolrConfig.class);

@Bean 
public SolrClient solrClient() {
    if(env == null ) 
    { 
        logger.error("Property file not loaded!!!"); 
        System.exit(1); 
    }
    String servername = env.getProperty("solr.server");
    return new  HttpSolrClient.Builder(servername)
                      .build();

}

@Bean
public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient client) throws Exception {
    return new SolrTemplate(client);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You class annotation is correct, but try the following within your method:

```
Properties _properties = new Properties();
_properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("solr.properties"));
String servername = _properties.getProperty("solr.server");
```

Comment: thanks that works if there is a way i could get it to work with spring would be great - it picks up my log4j from the same location..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing a [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) registered.

From Spring documentation of [`@PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html):

> In order to resolve ${...} placeholders in  definitions or
>   @Value annotations using properties from a PropertySource, **one must
>   register a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer**. This happens
>   automatically when using  in XML, but
>   **must be explicitly registered** using a static @Bean method when using
>   @Configuration classes.

So consider registering this bean:

```
   @Bean
   public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
     propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
      return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   }
```

Comment: This did not work I added this in the SolrConfig class